# Вывести совпадения Laravel + MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

Как вывести совпадения для пользователя -user_i = 1. Нужно вывести пользователей, которых лайкнул пользователь 1 и те пользователя, которые лайкнули этого пользователя

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Например пользователь 12 подходит под условие, но не знаю как это вывести

```
$users = DB::table('likes')
            ->leftJoin('users','users.id','=','likes.like_user')
            ->leftJoin('user_attributes','user_attributes.user_id','=','likes.like_user')
            ->select('user_attributes.fullname','user_attributes.avatar','user_attributes.country','user_attributes.city','user_attributes.age',
                'users.name','users.id','likes.created_at')
            ->where('likes.like_user','=', 'likes.user_id')
            ->where('likes.user_id','=', Auth::user()->id)
            ->paginate(15);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.user_id 
FROM likes t1
JOIN likes t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.like_user 
             AND t2.user_id = 1
             AND t1.like_user = 1
```

и, если я верно понимаю синтаксис, то

```
$users = DB::table(DB:raw('likes t1'))
       ->join(DB:raw('likes t2'), 't1.user_id', '=', 't2.like_user ')
       ->where('t2.user_id', '=', '1')
       ->where(' t1.like_user', '=', '1')
```

Comment: так, выводит только меня, пропускает того пользователя 12

Comment: @Aslero Если это сказано про SQL-запрос - не верю. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a3065cb03934a17c5ae3f3454491b926). А если про Laravel-код - так я ну очень толсто намекнул, что он может быть ошибочным.

Comment: все решил, нашел косяки

Comment: @Aslero Если несложно, укажите, в чём косяки-то... чтобы и мне знать на будущее.

Comment: пробелы были ->where('t1.like_user ') и в select указывать 't1.user_id'

Comment: @Aslero aaa... ок, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  l1.*
FROM
  likes l1
  JOIN likes l2 ON (l1.like_user = l2.user_id)
WHERE
  l1.user_id = 1 OR
  l1.like_user = 1
```

Comment: Ему оба нужны... чтобы была и прямая и обратная пары. А так только в одну сторону, но все.

Comment: @Akina в выборке будут оба пользователя

Comment: получается если я user_id = 1 лайкнул like_user =12 и соответственно пользователь user_id =12 лайкнул меня like_user = 1 то нужно выводить пользователя 12

Comment: @Aslero Мой запрос выведет двух пользователей. Если вам нужно только одного, то уберите условие ` l1.like_user = 1`

Answer (score 0):

рабочий код

```
$users = DB::table('likes AS t1')
            ->join('likes AS t2', 't1.user_id', '=', 't2.like_user')
            ->leftJoin('users','users.id','=','t1.user_id')
            ->leftJoin('user_attributes','user_attributes.user_id','=','t1.user_id')
            ->select('user_attributes.fullname','user_attributes.avatar','user_attributes.country','user_attributes.city','user_attributes.age',
                'users.name','users.id','t1.created_at')
            ->where('t2.user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
            ->where('t1.like_user', '=', Auth::user()->id)->distinct('t1.user_id')->get();
```